# jquery Struts2 Java $.getJSON params UTF-8 encoding (Tomcat 5.5)

Tags: java, jquery, utf-8, struts2

I'm getting mad with this:

Tomcat 5.5, JRE 1.6 (compliance level) using JDK 1.7

Headers:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Json request:

```
params = $("#formList").serializeArray();
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {...});
```

When I pass an ñ to alias parameter, on my localhost machine (win) is workin ok, but in production server (linux) I'm getting a double encoding for param or something similar:

**WebBrowserRequest (same request for localhost & production):**

userList.action?pagination.currentPage=1&pagination.sortColumn=&pagination.sortColumnOrder=&**user.alias=%C3%B1**&user.email=&selectedRole=-1&selectedCountry=-1&selectedTown=-1&selectedLanguage=-1&selectedUserEnabled=0&__multiselect_selectedCategories=&jsonRequest=true&back=false

**Server-side url output (localhost):**

userList.action?pagination.currentPage=1&jsonRequest=true&user.email=&selectedLanguage=-1&selectedTown=-1&selectedCountry=-1&pagination.sortColumn=&selectedRole=-1&back=false&**user.alias=Ã±**&selectedUserEnabled=0&pagination.sortColumnOrder=&__multiselect_selectedCategories=

**Server-side url output (production):**

userList.action?jsonRequest=true&selectedTown=-1&pagination.sortColumn=&**user.alias=ÃÂ±**&back=false&pagination.sortColumnOrder=&pagination.currentPage=1&user.email=&selectedLanguage=-1&selectedCountry=-1&selectedRole=-1&selectedUserEnabled=0&__multiselect_selectedCategories=

Comment: Which application server?

Comment: You should check this article. and almost all the character set issues will solved. http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html Specially thanks for BalusC

Comment: Set Tomcat connector attribute `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.

Comment: @AleksandrM It has no effect: <Connector port="9401" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved changing the getJSON (GET) request by $.ajax (POST):

getJson:

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
    showData(data);
}).error(function(data) {
    showFail(data);
});
```

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: params
}).done(function( data ) {
    showData(data,page);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    showFail(jqXHR, textStatus);
});
```